# How i can create HTML5 Map easily?

Tags: html, image, dictionary

I want to create map which changes the images when i click on it, or gives links to somewhere.

I know that this can be done with HTML5, i have to add coordinates, right?
The problem is that it will take years to do that manually with photoshop and to write all coordinates manually.... is there way to do it faster or with program?

Thats the code(if you dont know):

```
<img src ="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap ="#planetmap" />
<map name="planetmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun" />
<area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury" />
<area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus" />
</map>
```

This map for example: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Europe_map.png

Comment: Dreamweaver has some builtin functions to do so. You can then select the borders with a mouse-click. As i don't have dreamweaver on this pc, here's a video tutorial where you could find it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seWbi5UE4o4

Comment: You can use Illustrator to create vectorized shapes and export them as SVG to get the coordinates. (Or even use directly the SVGs). You can even use a SVG-HTML5 converter: http://www.professorcloud.com/svg-to-canvas/

Comment: What you are using in this example is an image map. This is not a HTML5 feature. It was introduced over a decade ago in HTML 3.2.

Comment: So you want to actually have shapes or simply use map to attach click events to part of a larger image?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [iiCreator](http://www.iicreator.com) to import your image, and then define the custom regions which you want to change, or showing a popup on mouseover.